# Data disappearing from SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-delete, sql-server-profiler

I have an issue where I have a web app using Entity Framework connected to a SQL Server database. At random intervals, the data in one of my tables keeps getting cleared down. About 90% of the data is deleted.

We have scoured through the web app and cannot find any delete statements at all let alone one on that table.

We have had SQL Server Profiler running but this has not picked up any delete statements. However, I also have an ON DELETE trigger on this table to copy deleted data to a back up table and this runs and triggers fine so there seems to be a conflict on whether delete statements have actually been run or not. There is also hundreds of GB of space on the server so lack of space isnt an issue.

We have investigated as much as we can to no avail and we are now out of ideas.

Therefore if anyone knows of any reason this could happen i would be very thankful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by the conflict when you talk about the on delete trigger. Your on delete trigger should have picked up all deleted records if it does not than someone disabled that trigger.

Comment: Do you have a foreign key with cascade delete somewhere ? Cascade delete should be banned from any database imho

Comment: A thought rather than a proper answer: could it be a MERGE? I've run across badly-written merges that accidentally deleted things before. I'm not sure whether they would need tracing differently in profiler, but might be worth a look.

Comment: I know SQL Server doesnt just delete anything thats why im trying to hunt down the cause. Truncate and drop would affect the whole table whereas we still have a few rows left afterwards so we have ruled them out. There are no foreign keys in the database that would cause a cascade delete and all cascading is turned off on the web app. What i mean by the conflict is that the trigger would have run on a delete statement but the profiler hasnt picked up a delete statement.

Comment: @JoDouglass could you explain more about MERGE and how this could cause it? Thats not something weve ever come across before

Comment: If you write the join conditions incorrectly the MERGE will act as if rows are missing from the source, and cause the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE to fire off.

Comment: Maybe it's a bad database initialization strategy?
DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges and DropCreateDatabaseAlways will make it seem like data disappears, because the table is recreated.

Maybe a developer is doing this for a side project, but targeting the wrong DB?

Also, if you can pinpoint the timeframe where it happens, check if you can run a profiler against that SQL instance.

Comment: @H.Lowette could you explain a bit further please?

Comment: You can tell your DbContext to initialize or migrate a database at startup. This happens with the Database.SetInitializer method. Search your code for that and see what's in there.

More info: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I did think that was potentially it last time however, commented the database initialization out and that didnt help. Plus wouldnt that affect the whole database? Whereas this is most of the data (not all) and only in 1 table

Comment: With a Seed method, the data in the other tables might be re-populated. I don't have all the info on your situation, so I was just suggesting another path to investigate.

Comment: If a MERGE is to blame, the solution is generally, to fix your join conditions, and instead of using them to narrow down what's updated or inserted, join on the full data set then use conditions in WHEN clauses to narrow down what is updated. Check the "Search Condition Guidelines" here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if there are any cascade delete is on. This query can help you with that :

```
SELECT name, 
       delete_referential_action_desc
FROM   sys.foreign_keys
```

I dont know if entity framework can have its own cascade delete, I dont use it. So I dont know how to check entity framework for cascade deletes.

Comment: this query returns NO_ACTION for all foreign keys therefore i assume there is no cascade delete? and EF side i have already checked and it is all turned off. +1 for the useful query though

Comment: Yes this means that cascade delete is not the source of your problem. I dont have any other idea where to look for your problem now, sorry